# Convert SQL server schema in Oracle DB schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

is there a tool able to convert a SQL SERVER schema into Oracle Schema?

Answer (score 1):

See if this documentation solves your problem.

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

Answer (score 1):

Oracle comes with a tool called SQL Developer. It contains a migration tool that can assist in the migration from various other DBMS.

The main website for SQL Developer is here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Here is a tutorial that explains how to convert from SQL Server to Oracle:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/sqldev/r30/SQLServerMigration/SQLServerMigration.htm